# Add GLSL shader to a VTKActor (VTK 6.1)

Tags: opengl, glsl, vtk

I'm trying to add a shader to a vtkActor into my application. I have different vtkActors and they must have different shaders each one.

I tried with the vtkShader2, vtkShaderProgram2 and vtkOpenGLProperty to set the program loaded with the shader to the actor, but it didn't work (vtk told me in a warning window that it has 4 shaders in the actor, the default shaders and mine).

Someone knows the right way to do it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I asked on vtk mailing list 2 months ago and I'm still waiting for an answer. They deprecated LoadMaterial in [vtk6.1](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkProperty-LoadMaterial-disappeared-in-VTK-6-1-td5726066.html) without giving any alternative. (Well, I haven't found any) If you can, the easiest way is to use LoadMaterial in vtk < 6.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution finally appeared in [vtk mailing list](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/GLSL-Shader-on-a-vtkActor-VTK-6-1-and-Qt-5-2-1-tt5727788.html#a5728023) after months of waiting! I didn't test it myself, but user @carlinhos says it works. He resumes the steps:

1. Create a shader file with the function propFuncFS(Fragment shader) or propFuncVS(Vertex shader).
2. Load the shader from disk.
3. Create a vtkShader2 and set the source code.
4. Create a vtkShaderProgram2 and initialize it (DO NOT BUILD THE PROGRAM).
5. Add the shader to the program.
6. Obtain the actor vtkOpenGLProperty and set the program
7. Set the shading on.

EDIT: Is @carlinhos you? I am feeding you your own answer? :)

Comment: Yes, it's me!!!!! I forgot to post it here :D hahahaha

Thanks for posting, anyone who has any doubt don't hesitate to contact me ;).

Answer (score 4):

After running into this myself, I'd like to add a little more to mpcarlos87 / carlinhos / Nil's answer...

The code below is the smallest that I could make an informative working sample. Key points are:

- vtkSmartPointer use means less need to clean-up ptrClass->Delete() style
- smart pointers also do automatic casting: vtkRenderWindow* to vtkOpenGLRenderWindow* for SetContect(), which is nice
- inline frag shader definition is good for fast testing, but bad for every other reason (use with care!)
- inline frag shader is very sensitive to new lines (\n) for things like #version

```cpp
#include "vtkConeSource.h"
#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkCamera.h"
#include "vtkActor.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkShader2.h"
#include "vtkShaderProgram2.h"
#include "vtkShader2Collection.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkOpenGLProperty.h"


int main()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkConeSource> cone = vtkConeSource::New();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> coneMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
    coneMapper->SetInputConnection( cone->GetOutputPort() );

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> coneActor = vtkActor::New();
    coneActor->SetMapper( coneMapper );

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> ren= vtkRenderer::New();
    ren->AddActor( coneActor );

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer( ren );

    const char* frag = "void propFuncFS(void){ gl_FragColor = vec4(255,0,0,1);}";

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkShaderProgram2> pgm = vtkShaderProgram2::New();
    pgm->SetContext(renWin);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkShader2> shader=vtkShader2::New();
    shader->SetType(VTK_SHADER_TYPE_FRAGMENT);
    shader->SetSourceCode(frag);
    shader->SetContext(pgm->GetContext());

    pgm->GetShaders()->AddItem(shader);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOpenGLProperty> openGLproperty = 
    static_cast<vtkOpenGLProperty*>(coneActor->GetProperty());
    openGLproperty->SetPropProgram(pgm);
    openGLproperty->ShadingOn();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 360; ++i)
    {
        renWin->Render();
        ren->GetActiveCamera()->Azimuth( 1 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Took a bit of trial and error to get the above working - hope that it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i got the shaders working with the help of the mailing list of VTK just 4 days ago, i forgot to post it here.

Your answer is the same as the one i got from the mailing list :)! (The "steps" are described above by Nil)

Comment: You code should work (i didn't test it but it seems  right) =)

Comment: I tested it! Non-functional 'examples' are the bane of my life... Glad that you got it working.